# Are we "experts"?

Tags: discussion, tags, answers

Stack Overflow is the [**#1 reference site**](https://www.alexa.com/topsites/category/Top/Reference) on the planet, and is the [**63rd most visited**](https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com) website overall. With over [**200 page views *per second***](http://stackoverflow.com.websiteoutlook.com/), surely it's considered an authoritative place to find answers to programming questions.

---

Keeping that in mind, I submit that:

- if an SO member is ranked as **[the top user](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers)** for a given tag, then by definition, **it would *not* be an exaggeration to refer to that person as *an EXPERT* on that topic**.

*Agreed?*

---

> ## Definitions of `Expert`:
>
> • A person who is very knowledgeable about or skillful in a particular area  <sup><sub>([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expert))</sub></sup>
>   • Having or displaying special skill or knowledge derived from training or experience <sub>([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expert))</sub>
>   • A person with a high level of knowledge or skill relating to a particular subject or activity <sub>([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expert))</sub>
>   • Someone with prolonged experience through practice and education in a particular field <sup><sub>([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert))</sub></sup>

---

Given the huge number of users the site has, I think the same title could be safely applied to, perhaps, the **top 5 to 10% of users** for a particular tag.

**Is this correct?**  Is there a *more technical* definition/qualification of the term ***expert***, when referring to technical knowledge (based on one's ability to answer questions on the topic)?

...I think this is an important term for us to clarify as a community, because it affects not only the perception that other professionals have of us, *and* the perception we have of ourselves as programmers.

Comment: What use does this serve? If you want to call yourself an expert, go ahead.

Comment: You can become a top tag user answering only trivial questions that do not require any in-depth expertise in anything.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure I'm a top 5% user in several languages that I've never written a line in my entire life, presumably through weird tagging

Comment: If a tag has one question, does that make me an expert if I am the only person who answered it?

Comment: Just checked, I'm in the top 5% for `netbeans` (don't even really know what that is), `xml` (definitely not an in-depth expert), `prototypejs` (used it a little bit 10 years ago), `windows-7` (haven't developed a line of code on Windows since 1999). Also in the top 10% for `jsp` (don't even speak Java), `yii` (never used even once), `kohana` (never used). So the answer is a resounding "no"

Comment: Ha! I'm in the top 20 for both 6502 (in fact, number 7) and Objective-C. I'm not an expert in either.

Comment: I disagree. I command the [#1 answerer spot in \[css\]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/topusers), but I'm not a CSS "expert". I'm a CSS "guru".

Comment: I feel this is on-topic because **SO describes itself as a place to get "expert information/answers"**, and **MSO is a place for discussing SO.**

Comment: @Pekka웃 if you've never used the language, I assure you, you are not an expert in it.

Comment: I agree this is on topic. Suggested title change: "Does being a high-ranking user in a tag always imply expertise?"

Comment: @RobertLongson - obviously statistics require a dataset of a reasonable size

Comment: @Pekka웃 maybe you should stop adding weird tags to questions you answered then ...

Comment: @rene I'm going to have the last laugh when I score that $200/hour `netbeans` consulting gig!!!!!

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Damn, Kohana. The CodeIgniter knockoff that uh, did it gain more than a mediocre amount of traction?

Comment: I thought experts are at [hyphenated site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphenated-site)

Comment: That depends on how you read their URL

Comment: You can become a top user in a tag by amount of time spent answering questions that do not require deep expertise. Wrongly applied tags may apply to. You may also be in a niche environment be top user on a numbers basis.

Comment: The top experts have used SO lookup for years and probably have an account with some rep.  They're probably not very active  now because they don't have much free time for volunteering and it's too difficult to find anything worth answering:(

Answer (score 14):

SO is the place to get answers to practical programming questions. Full stop.

Its workflow is designed with that sole goal in mind. **It's not designed to bring users with the best expertize onto top, but rather users who provide the most net value to the developer community at large with their answers -- regardless of the level of expertize that those answers require.**

So the answer, [to quote @Pekka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370127/are-we-experts#comment603641_370127), "is a resounding "NO"".

Comment: This is true, although obviously there's several great experts who are also top-ranking SO users. It's just not wise to always assume this is the case.

Comment: Of course, we should not consider John Skeet .. he's the only expert here!

Comment: @Pekka웃 that's exactly what I say. There may be a correlation, but no causality.